# Download using git without repo data and in the local folder

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to download a copy of a Github project using git:

- without also downloading the internal /.git/ folder.  (I will generate my own)
- to my current directory, not into the repo's folder name.

I want to download the project into the root of my website and not into a project subfolder.

If I do this:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/some_github_account/project_1.git
```

Everything downloads but it places it all into a folder in my document root called 'project_1' and inside that is a /.git/ folder which I also do not want.

```
/home/bob/www/project_1/
/home/bob/www/project_1/.git/
```

What is the leanest, meanest way to download all the files from a project directly into the folder I'm in without all the repo stuff, using git?

Comment: "without also downloading the internal /.git/ folder. (I will generate my own)"—do you ever intend to contribute updates to the original project, or incorporate updates from the upstream project into your own code? If so, I urge you to reconsider. Having commits with hashes that match the upstream has critical benefits.

Comment: Note that Github has a "Download ZIP" feature where you can export the contents of a branch without the .git folder. You could then unzip that where you like.

Comment: Try `git archive` and then extract it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, in the end, it wasn't one answer that solved all my problems but a combination of suggestions and additional research that helped me get exactly what I needed.

Some of what I needed has to be done by hand when first setting up a client with a new site connected to GitHub, the rest I'll do in PHP via the shell_exec() function.

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/modusinternet/Custodian-CMS.git /tmp/Custodian-CMS
rm -rf /tmp/Custodian-CMS/.git
shopt -s dotglob
cp -r /tmp/Custodian-CMS/* /home/YOUR_ACCOUNT/YOUR_WEB_FOLDER
rm -rf /tmp/Custodian-CMS
git init
git add --all
git config --global user.email ""
git config --global user.name ""
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ON_GITHUB/YOUR_REPO_ON_GITHUB.git
git push -u origin master
```

That pulls down a copy of what I need, cleans it up, puts it where it belongs, initializes git on the new location, connects it to my new repo and pushes everything up so I can start working on it.

In my case, I don't need backward compatibility because every client I work with completely changes the starting templates anyway.

I'll add a button in the admin to help deal with FTP uploads directly to the server later but this is the code I'll use to resyncing it with the repo:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "From server"
git push -u origin master
```

Special thanks to Andrea Peekatchu Follack, rishabh agarwal,and CodeWizard for their suggestions.

Comment: I chose to use 'cp' instead of 'mv' because I ran into problems with some folders already containing content.  I'm sure it will be rare but I just didn't want to have to deal with it in the future.  My template base is also only about 90 files in total (2 megs) so I'm fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not intending to push your commits to contribute to the project you're cloning, there is one step you can take, to allow yourself to have your own remote in that folder.

Run

```
rm -rf .git
```

to remove the cloned git repo from the folder, and then follow your usual steps in creating your own, ie

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

then add your own repo

```
git remote add add origin git@github.com/account/repository
```

You get the point.

If you take that route, just make sure it's your own work you're committing, not just a complete replica of someone else's build. Hope this helps, even if it's not exactly the way you were hoping. Git is set up the way it is for good reason, but the workarounds are there, for those with special requirements. The main point is that first line.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to download a copy of a Github project using git:

The answer is No.

When you `clone` a git repo it will create `.git` folder for you and you cant avoid it.

If you wish to download the sources only you can use `github` *download* feature which will download the sources as zip file
[image]

If you wish to download the projetc into a diffrent folder use the

```
git clone --depth=1 https://.../project.git <YOUR_FOLDER_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/some_github_account/project_1.git .
rm -rf ./.git
```

It will clone the project in the current folder and remove the .git folder.

You can now add your git settings using `git init` command.